# IE9 file download unresponsive?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Normally when I click on a file in IE9, the download popup shows at the bottom of the screen either asking me to save/open/cancel or shows download progress. Randomly, when I click on a file, it won't do anything at all. But if I sit and stare at it doing nothing at, it'll eventually pop up and ask me to save/open/cancel. It doesn't matter if the file is 8MB or 8KB. The browser isn't unresponsive, just the download manager.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a fluke. It was only happening on one user's computer. We dropped the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a program like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what the file requests are doing for those 'random' ones. You might find that it's actually the server hosting the file that is less than responsive.

Another thought would be the download location settings, does it always ask you for a location or do you have one set? Is it a network path? An external drive? Anything that could make the initial write lag rather than the read could cause a similar experience.

Comment: So far, I've only seen it happen on one workstation on the office network. The file is fetched through a generic handler (.ashx) that grabs it from a database. I haven't been able to recreate it on any other workstations yet.